# Not able to read InputStream

Tags: java, servlets

The following few lines are part of my servlet that give me an error "java.lang.NullPointerException"

```
 ServletContext context = getServletContext();
       InputStream kapil= context.getResourceAsStream("Desktop/images.jpg");
//the above line generates the exception
    BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(kapil);
```

Comment: I'm not sure you can use "Desktop/" as a file path... On windows it's actually somewhere like C:/users/so_and_so/.../desktop (search it up)

Comment: @Raeki No but I have used paths like this in the rest of my code whereever i had to open files or delete files etc. And also I haven't written the whole path in the question.

Comment: Seams you havn't posted the problematic code, where is `input`?

Comment: @MouseEvent There is no parameter in my whole code by that name.

Comment: @MouseEvent  
InputStream kapil= context.getResourceAsStream("Desktop/images.jpg");
The above line actually gives "java.lang.NullPointerException" whereas there is file that exists at that path

Comment: For a servlet, the resource must be available within the servlet container (which would not include an image on the Desktop).

Comment: @AndrewThompson Yeah I got that, I was just reading my notes. I used InputStream kapil = new FileInputStream("Desktop/images.jpg");
Is it a bad coding method? Its working but.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Beacuse the above code that I wrote was from your suggestion on my other question.

Comment: do you need the servlet to return the image file?  if the image is static content, the servlet container will be able to return this without you doing any coding.

Comment: 'The above line' does *not* throw a NullPointerException unless 'context' is null, which would indicate something seriously wrong with your Servlet. More likely it *returns* null, which would indicate that the resource named doesn't exist. Which is a completely different issue.

Comment: @Chris yes I need the servlet to return an image but after some editing so I need to get it in the BufferedImage. I understand that a servlet cannot access a file on Desktop,, it should be inside the servlet container but what would that container be that I dont understand.

Comment: @EJP The resource does exist. I am able to access it using the File class.

Comment: @kapil - does the image need to live in the Desktop folder?  The code should work if you move the Desktop folder to the root of your webapp (at the same level as the WEB-INF folder).

Comment: @Chris Yes I did that and it worked. Thanks a lot. :-)

Comment: @kapil - note that your users will also be able to directly download the images without your servlet.  if you want to prevent this, put the Desktop folder in the WEB-INF folder and change your code to: getResourceAsStream("WEB-INF/Desktop/images.jpg");

Comment: @Chris Then also if someone knows the path they will be able to download it directly right??

Comment: @Kapil - yes.  anything in the parent of WEB-INF can be downloaded directly.

Comment: @Chris I'll do that. I'll move it to a dynamic folder, still inside WEB-INF directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You edited your post. Are you sure it's a `NullPointerException` and not a `IllegalArgumentException`?

JavaDocs:

[ServletContext.getResourceAsStream()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29) will return `null` if it cannot find the file you are looking for.

[ImageIO.read()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#read%28java.io.InputStream%29) throws an `IllegalArgumentExeception` when the parameter is null. The mentioned `input` is probably the ImageIO input parameter.

I'd guess that indeed the Input file isn't found.

That would match your original posts problem. Try the following:

```
ServletContext context = getServletContext();
InputStream kapil= context.getResourceAsStream("Desktop/images.jpg");
if (kapil != null){
    //the above line generates the exception
    BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(kapil);
} else {
   // Use a logging framework if you have it.
   System.out.println("The input stream is null!");
}
```

Comment: Sorry I took so long to mark your answer. I never knew you had answered.